# Зачем подняли прошлогодний плохой вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов

Увидел сегодня вопрос: [Отсутствует запятая (ORA-00917)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637753/%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-ora-00917)

Под вопросом стоит плашка:

> Поднят на главную страницу участником Дух сообщества♦ 5 часов назад.
>
> Вопрос имеет ответы, которые могут быть плохими или хорошими; система сделала его активным, чтобы они могли быть пересмотрены.

Вообще-то вопрос вызван опечаткой (точнее, тремя опечатками), все три опечатки были перечислены там же в комментарии к вопросу две минуты спустя. Имхо, вопрос надо было просто закрыть, там нечего улучшать ни в вопросе, ни в ответах. (Тревогу про опечатку уже отправил)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Причина подъема указана на плашке:

> Вопрос имеет ответы, которые могут быть плохими или хорошими; система сделала его активным, чтобы они могли быть пересмотрены.

Так как в указанном вопросе не отмечен лучший ответ и у единственного ответа рейтинг 0, система поднимает вопрос, чтобы были приняты необходимые меры:

1. пересмотрен сам вопрос: отредактирован, оценен, возможно закрыт либо удален
2. пересмотрены присутствующие ответы: оценены, отмеченные как лучшие
3. даны новые ответы

---

А также на [странице Духа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0?tab=profile):

> случайным образом раз в час поднимаю старые вопросы без принятых ответов и ответов с положительным рейтингом в общем списке **для того, чтобы они получили чуточку дополнительного внимания**;

Comment: А, так это автоматически происходит. Понятно. Внимание вопросу я уже уделил :)